# Footnote symbol bold, small in text, normalsize in footnote

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I should know this... I'd like to have the footnote figure in bold face and small (textsuperscript) in the running text and bold face and normal size in the footnote text at the bottom of the page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\def\thempfn{\textbf{\thefootnote}}% bold figures
\newfootnote[plain]{default}
\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{A totally cool footnote} world!
\end{document}
```

I am using bigfoot. I have managed to get the footnote symbol bold and superscript in both the running text and the bottom, but it should be only small in the running text.

Comment: Just to play around, can you add the code for making the number bold?

Comment: @egreg done with the edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard model of LaTeX (kept by `bigfoot`) is to use `\@makefnmark` both for the marker in the running text and in the footnote text.

Here's a way to detach them from each other:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \parindent1em\noindent
  \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\MOD@makefnmark}%
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\MOD@makefnmark}{\normalfont\bfseries\@thefnmark\ }
\patchcmd\@makefnmark
  {\normalfont}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newfootnote[plain]{default}

\textheight=2cm % to keep the output small

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{A totally cool footnote} world!

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't add formatting instruction in `\thempfn`.